# Spring security implementation for Oauth2 rest client that persists client_id client_secret token_info_url in database, not in application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a spring boot application that makes various REST calls to external / other servers, each of those servers will need distinct client_id, client_secret, etc and there could be dozens or hundreds of different such credential sets.

All of the oauth2 examples I've looked at keep these in a single application.properties / yml file which is only a single set of credentials.

I can see how to implement my own classes to persist this in a database but someone else must have already invented this wheel.

Tell me what projects to look at please.

Comment: It looks like there is only an in-memory implementation, see [ClientRegistrationRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/registration/ClientRegistrationRepository.html).

Comment: Thanks, I also found JdbcOAuth2AuthorizedClientService which appears to have most of what I want, now just looking for more documentation / examples that show it in action